# How to Enable Telephony Actions in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android

I'm using android studio for app development and genymotion for emulator. I have created the virtual device of API-22 in genymotion and the emulator is working good but I'm not able to perform telephony actions in ADM like sending the sms to the emulator.The telephony actions in ADM is disabled.
please can anyone help me out... [Android Device Monitor_Window_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn9r1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html) concerning the DDMS will find it said the tab "Emulator Control" [is no longer supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html#ops-location).

The support for these features are now provided directly on the [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#extended)

Answer (score 0):

device monitor in android studio only works for the default emulators.
It does not work for genymotion or mobile device.